# Solspace Favorites Count inside Favorites Saved tag

Tags: solspace

This may be a simple yes/no but is it possible to show the Favorites Count within the Favorites Saved tag?

Currently I'm trying to achieve this by using the Favorites Count tag within the Favorites Saved tag but unfortunately I'm getting a weird encrypted looking number outputted on the front-end.

I've even tried adding the count tag as a snippet within the saved tag as I know this sometimes helps with channel entries within channel entries, but not luck.

Is what I'm doing possible? Or is there some variable for the saved tag that will output the count that I'm missing in the documentation?

Note: When I separate the count from the saved tag, I get a number, so the tag is correct. However I would prefer the count within the saved tag because I am using ajax to action the save and would like the count to update "on-the-fly" along with the saved/unsaved status.

Comment: How about an embed?

Comment: Hmm, I thought that would have solved it but things aren't really behaving if it's a listings page, i.e. blog top-level page with 10 latest posts.

Not to worry. It's more of a 'nice to have' rather than a requirement.

Thanks for getting back to me though. Can I put a feature request in for the variable to be added to the saved tag please?

Comment: Could you show some example code of what you have now in the OP?